# how do i do a random swap but impose a limit of how far that number can move from its original position?

Tags: matlab

A set of 20 numbers have been stored inside a vector `d`, for example:

```
d = [ 5 6 7 8 9 ....]
```

I use

```
i = randperm(length(d));
d = d(i);
```

to randomly shuffle the numbers inside the matrix.

However, I need to find a way to limit the shuffle to ensure that the number does not move more then "5" places from its original position?

Meaning that if originally `d(2) = 6`, the final position of `6` should only move to `d(1)` to `d(2+5)`.

Note, `d(1)` because the numbers cannot move to a negative position.

Any help on this would be appreciated! also, if there is a more efficient way with the shuffling please kindly let me know!

Comment: Are the numbers to be moved picked at random? Can a number move twice?

Comment: the numbers can be moved any number times but cant move more then a fixed distance in this case that would be 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to create a random permutation and swap bad indices as long as no index violates the distance rule.

```
d=data
delta=5;
i= randperm(length(d));
v=badPosition(i);
while(v~=0)
    %lower bound for position     
    a=max(1,i(v)-5);
    %upper bound for position
    A=min(numel(i),i(v)+5);
    spos=randi([a,A]);
    h=i(v);
    i(v)=i(spos);
    i(spos)=h;
    v=badPosition(i);
end
d=d(i)
```

---

```
function pos=badPosition(indices)
delta=5;
allPos=(find(indices>(1:numel(indices))+delta|indices<(1:numel(indices))-delta));
if numel(allPos)>0
    pos=allPos(randi(numel(allPos)));
else
    pos=0;
end
end
```

---

`badPosition` is a function which returns 0 if all indices are okay or one index which violates the distance rule. If multiple violations exists, a *random* index is chosen.

Comment: hi! thanks for your help! could you explain how you would created 'badPosition' as a function?
what i seem to get is "Undefined function 'badPosition' for input arguments of type 'double'."

Comment: You have to create a function, which returns one index that violates the +-5 distance. Check all indices and pick a random one. I did not include it to my answer, because I'm currently using a PC without matlab, but it should be solvable in 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: I updated the code (now faster) and added the `badPosition`-function.

Comment: If `data` is long, this will be very slow... how large is your dataset?

Comment: I made another update, now it runs in less than 10s for data of size 10000. A vectorized version would be faster, but currently I have no idea to vectorize without loosing equal probabilities.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work!! 'data' is around 30+ long!
Another qns. it seems to work if i run it once. meaning it keeps within the +5 violation. but if i run it consecutively with the same data set twice or more then it does not.
Any way to make such the case where it keeps with its original +5 violation no matter how much i run it?

Comment: @user3150845 Run it on the orginal data, not the randomized data. That way it will never violate. and there is no real difference (unless you're hoping for it to converge via the central limit theorum?)

Comment: @DanielR takes me 88 seconds for 20000 now (which is a huge improvement but still slow. But that doesn't matter since we're talking about around 30), however it does seem to have twice the probability of choosing -5?

Comment: @Dan: I don't see the double probability for -5. How did you get this conclusion?

Comment: @DanielR from this: `hist(i - (1:20000))`

Comment: @Which generates a hist with 10 segments, there are 11 decisions. Try `hist(i - (1:20000),11)`

Comment: Thanks both of you all for advice on this! probably running it on the original data set. Im trying to use this in conjunction with heuristic algorithm to solve for a mathematical optimization solution. Thanks so much for all the help! As you can see not too good with this since im new at it! Really appreciated the help given!

Answer (score 0):

This solution will scale better:

```
n=2000;
I = 1:n;

k = 5;

for ii = 1+k:n-k
    t = I(ii);
    s = t + randi(2*k,1)-k;

    if abs(I(s) - ii) <= k

        I(ii) = I(s);
        I(s) = t;

    end
end
```

Then do `data(I)`. This doesn't properly account for the edge cases but I think you can fairly easily adjust for that.

I tried it for `n=100000` and it ran in less than a second.

However the shuffling is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: This does not generate all permutations with an equal probability. Less than 1/22 of the indices are shifted by +5, expected is 1/11